# Positioning / Setting Direction of Confetti Android

Tags: android, kotlin, direction

I am developing an android application. I have implemented the following library:
`nl.dionsegijn:konfetti:1.3.2`. This library allows you to display confetti, but I have a slight issue. I am trying to make the confetti come from the top but it only comes from the top left corner. Refer to the below screenshot.

[image: click link to see screenshot]

Here is the code from my xml layout file:

```
<nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.KonfettiView
        android:id="@+id/viewKonfetti"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.KonfettiView>
```

Here is the code from my kotlin file:

```
viewKonfetti.build()
   .addColors(Color.parseColor("#FFD700"), Color.parseColor("#FD7F20"))
   .setDirection(0.0, 359.0)
   .setSpeed(1f, 5f)
   .setFadeOutEnabled(true)
   .setTimeToLive(2000L)
   .addShapes(Shape.Square, Shape.Circle)
   .addSizes(Size(12))
   .streamFor(500, StreamEmitter.INDEFINITE)
```

[here is the link to the github repository of this library](https://github.com/DanielMartinus/Konfetti)

Any help as to how I can make the confetti come from the top would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you take a look through that library yourself? `setPosition` seems pretty relevant: https://github.com/DanielMartinus/Konfetti/blob/0782b046ff03b6597f58acae8dc42c6ccc8e8d34/konfetti/src/main/java/nl/dionsegijn/konfetti/ParticleSystem.kt#L45

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is My Confetti Coming from the Corner of the Screen in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67210861/why-is-my-confetti-coming-from-the-corner-of-the-screen-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.setPosition(-50f, konfettiView.getWidth() + 50f, -50f, -50f)
```